# Overland travel - Thai visa requires tickets in and out

Tags: visas, thailand

I am an Indian citizen living in Singapore and will be travelling overland from Malaysia into Thailand and then onto Laos. The visa form (online) states that I should upload tickets showing that I enter and leave Thailand. How do I go about this? My options are:

1. Print a flight itinerary and say that I will be travelling over air.
2. Don't upload any tickets and submit my visa for processing anyway.

EDIT: Rephrasing the question, can I apply for the visa with a flight itinerary and then go over land in the end or will there be problems if I do this?

Comment: How are you travelling overland? Car hire? Coach/bus/train? Foot? Bicycle? Whichever it is, have you booked anything for this travel or are you buying it once you're there? Do you have hotel bookings in Malaysia, Thailand and Laos?

Comment: I haven't decided or booked anything. The first thing I'm doing is the visa